# devise - not able to confirm user email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I keep getting taken to 'Resend confirmation instructions' page when i click on the 'confirm email' link after creating a user account.

I'm able to change a user's password using the 'forgot password' link w/o a problem and I'm seeing what looks like a valid token.

my mailer looks good IMO:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource,
:confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

this is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


      devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, 
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable
      validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
      validates :first_name, :presence => true
      validates :last_name, :presence => true
      validates :dob, :presence => true
      validates :gender, :presence => true

     def confirm!
      super
      if confirmed_at_changed? and confirmed_at_was.nil?
        UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver if self.confirmed_at_changed?
      end
    end

    end
```

Any idea what needs to be done to get it comfirmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.confirm_within = 0.days
```

to:

```
config.confirm_within = 2.days
```

fixed the issue